# Can an array be a top level JSON object? (in Objective C, Stig Brautaset's library)

Tags: iphone, json

I'm writing an Objective C / iOS module to parse text files into JSON dictionaries, using Stig Brautaset's JSON library.

Is there a simple way to parse a single JSON file into an array of dictionary objects, or do I have to create a single dictionary object and pull the different objects out of it?

As background I'm currently using multiple files, one per object.  My JSON files look something like this:

```
{
 "colorname": "red",
 "foos": [
   {
    "type": "cherry",
    "category": "fruit"
   },
   {
    "type": "redvines",
    "category": "bar"
   }
 ]
}
```

```
{
 "colorname": "green",
 "foos": [...]
}
```

```
{
 "colorname": "blue",
 "foos": [...]
}
```

*etc.*

My parsing function goes like this:

```
NSMutableArray *fooColors = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease] 

for (NSString *thisFile in fileList) { 
  NSString *entireFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:thisFile
                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                              error:nil];
  NSDictionary *fooList = (NSDictionary*)[entireFile JSONValue];
  [fooColors addObject:dataObject];
}
```

But I'd rather have all the JSON objects in a single file.  Would I do it all in a single top level dictionary like this?

```
{
 "colors": [
   {
    "colorname": "red",
    "foos": [
      {
       "type": "cherry",
       "category": "fruit"
      },
      {...}
    ]
   },
   {"colorname": "green",
    "foos":[...]
   },
   {"colorname": "blue",
    "foos":[...]
   },
   *etc.*
 ]
}
```

Is there a simpler way to dispense with the first two and last two lines of the JSON text and read it in as an array of dictionary objects?  If so, what would the parsing function look like?

Apologies in advance if this is a newbie question.

Answer (score 1):

The outermost object in JSON can be an array. It doesn't have to be a record/dictionary. SBJSON will return an NSArray to you.

```
[
   {
    "colorname": "red",
    "foos": [
      {
       "type": "cherry",
       "category": "fruit"
      },
      {...}
    ]
   },
   {"colorname": "green",
    "foos":[...]
   },
   {"colorname": "blue",
    "foos":[...]
   },
   *etc.*
 ]
```